# Python flask, a cleaner way to update a SQLAlchemy record

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

is there any way to perform database update in flask better than this:

```
@author_blueprint.route("/updateAuthor/<int:author_id>", methods=["GET","POST"])
def updateAuthor(author_id):
    author = Author.query.get(author_id)
    form = AuthorForm(request.form, obj=author)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        author.firstName = form.firstName.data //line 6
        author.lastName = form.lastName.data //line 7
        author.university = form.university.data.name //line 8
        author.department = form.department.data.name //line 9
        author.email = form.email.data //line 10
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Updated author Successfully")
        return redirect(url_for("author.createAuthor"))
    authors = author.query.all()
    return render_template("author/author.html", title="authors", form=form, authors=authors)
```

my record is updated using this way but I done want to write all the fields one by one to do the update like in lines 6 to 10

Comment: I think you are looking for `Form.populate_obj()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46610070/6560549

Answer (score 1):

just warp it up with some function s.a

```
def update(author, form):
    author.firstName = form.firstName.data
    author.lastName = form.lastName.data 
    author.university = form.university.data.name
    author.department = form.department.data.name
    author.email = form.email.data
```